# Does seperate windows system reserved boot partition provide increased fault tolerance?

Tags: windows

With Windows 7, i have a choice of having a seperate SYSTEM RESERVED partition holding the operating system boot files, or merging them into the Windows Partition thus simplifying my disc layout. My question is, does having my boot files in a separate SYSTEM RESERVED partition provide increased fault tolerance, to say, boot file corruption ? eg. the dreaded NTLDR missing error.

Comment: Thanks for the off-topic advice. I am new to this remarkable resource - am i right in thinking stackoverflow=coding and superuser=setup ?

Comment: + serverfault = professional/enterprise network/server configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the purpose of the System Reserved partition is not fault tolerance, but BitLocker - Windows' full-volume encryption feature.

When you enable BitLocker, each sector in the OS partition is encrypted with a key derived from a single Full-Volume Encryption Key aka. the **FVEK**.

The **FVEK** is in turn encrypted by a secondary key, the Volume Master key (or **VMK**) and stored alongside the encrypted data on the OS partition.

Now, since the boot records and file system of your operating system is fully encrypted, we can't really launch the operating system on startup - *this is where the SYSTEM RESERVED partition comes in handy*!

The (unencrypted) SYSTEM RESERVED partition contains a pre-boot environment consisting of a bootloader and 1 (or more) encrypted copies of the **VMK**.

The bootloader decrypts the **VMK**, in turn allowing decryption of the **FVEK**, which then enables the decryption of the OS partition*

If you enable BitLocker and don't have the system reserved partition in place, you'll have to re-partition the disk.

---

*) *this is a very simplified description of the bootloading process on a BitLocker-encrypted computer, the process itself is obviously much more complex and tamper-proof*